# How to make my dialog to hide when i open any other window

Tags: java, jface

I am using a jface dialog, and now i am facing a problem where no matter which window you open  this dialog will appear on top of that. So i need to hide or show it such that it should come only on its parent window, not on all the windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are passing the correct window as the parent shell to the dialog.